# UIAlertController moves leftBarButtonItem down

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, uialertcontroller

I've created a `UIAlertController` with the preferred style of `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert`. The alert shows when the `leftBarButtonItem` is tapped.  I created a `UIBarButtonItem` property called `backButton` and set the `leftBarButtonItem = self.backButton`.  This is working as designed. I'm not using storyboards.

The problem is that the `leftBarButtonItem` moves down (my guess: about 20pts) when the alert shows.  Why is this happening?

I know how to show/hide the button so the user can't see that the button when it has moved down.  However, that sucks.  Why is it happening in the first place?

I haven't found ***any*** similar issues online.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
self.backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed)];
[self.backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-arrow-grey"]];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.backButton;
```

in backButtonPressed:

```
{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil; //to hide backButton because it moves down
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My title" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *actionLeave = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Leave" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:...//which works correctly

    UIAlertAction *actionCancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Go back" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.backButton; //to show backButton again now that the alert is dismissed
        //other things happen here that work as designed
    }];

    [alertController addAction:actionLeave];
    [alertController addAction:actionCancel];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

Comment: No idea, but 20pts is the size of status bar to me so that is the first place I would look.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I also encountered this issue. Searching for other issues about vertical mis-positioning of the left bar button item took me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311837/pressing-right-bar-button-item-moves-left-bar-button-items). The gist of it is that this problem occurs, for unknown reasons, if you have a bar button item that has an image, but an empty string as it's title. Set the title to a single space instead of just an empty string:

```
self.backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed)];
```

I don't know if it will fix it for you, but it mostly did for me - the button still does a slight 'jump' animation as though it's being newly created (but only the first time it appears) - but it stays at the same vertical position.

**Edit:** Passing in *nil* as the title also removes the extraneous animation. Seems like this is just a peculiarity in how iOS handles whitespace strings as titles.

Comment: setting to nil fixed it.  Thanks so much!  What an incredibly strange bug.  =D

Comment: I've caught this bug not only with AlertController. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is so odd that the fix is to assign value to the title. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
 barbutton.title = nil;
```

Set title nil and this work for me.